# Paper wallet secret Santa?

Tags: paper-wallet

I'm planning to contribute a Paper wallet as Secret Santa gift.  This would require the recipient to learn a bit about bitcoin and set up their own wallet in order to use the value.  What's the best approach for this?  Which paper wallet system should I use?  An important requirement is that it come with very clear instructions for the recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BitAddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org/) creates usable paper wallet PDFs. It does not have instructions however.

But a quick google brought me to **[this guide](https://blockchain.info/wallet/paper-tutorial) explaining how to use the BitAddress paper wallet**. It mentions you how you can add the address as watch only to the Blockchain.info mobile app and how you can spend the received funds from the address by scanning the private key QR code.

So what you could do is get the PDF from BitAddress.org and manually edit it to add the URL to the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

[This wallet design](https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/holiday-design/):

1) Has a holiday feel

2) Includes basic instructions on the back for safekeeping and redeeming.

3) Has a number of tamper-evident and idiot-proof features to prevent revelation of private key.

[image: Wallet sealed with optional hologram tape]